# Can you use C++ templates to specify a collection type and the specialization of that type?

Tags: c++, templates, collections

Example, I want to specialize a class to have a member variable that is an stl container, say a vector or a list, so I need something like:

```
template <class CollectionType, class ItemType>
class Test
{
public:
    CollectionType<ItemType> m_collection;
};
```

So I can do:

```
Test  t = Test<vector, int>();
t.m_collection<vector<int>> = vector<int>();
```

But this generates

```
test.cpp:12: error: `CollectionType' is not a template
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not do it like this?

```
template <class CollectionType>
class Test
{
public:
    CollectionType m_collection;
};

Test  t = Test<vector<int> >();
t.m_collection = vector<int>();
```

If you need the itemtype you can use `CollectionType::value_type`.

EDIT: in response to your question about creating a member function returning the value_type, you do it like this:

```
typename CollectionType::value_type foo();
```

You add the typename because CollectionType has not been bound to an actual type yet. So there isn't a value_type it could look up.

Comment: Good answer: this way Test is more general since it can work even with non-templated container.

Comment: I'm not sure I can do that since I need to write a member function that returns an object of the Item type. 

I can't do 

    CollectionType::value_type * advance() 

for example.

Comment: @justinhj: Why not? Why can't you use CollectionType::value_type?

Comment: CollectionType::value_type test2Get();

gives
    test3.cpp:30: error: expected `;' before "test2Get"

Comment: From the STL docs it looks like value_type should be called on an iterator rather than a collection?

Comment: containers are required to define several member types, such as reference, size_type, and value_type. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/ at the bottom, and the requirements are in section 23.1 "Container requirements" of the standard

Comment: You need to add typename before CollectionType::value_type. That's a common mistake when dealing with template members.

Answer (score 16):

What you want is a template template parameter:

```
template <template <typename> class CollectionType, class ItemType>
class Test
{
public:
    CollectionType<ItemType> m_collection;
};
```

What we did here is specifying that the first template parameter, i.e. `CollectionType`, is a type template. Therefore, `Test` can only be instantiated with a type that is itself a template.

However, as @Binary Worrier pointed in the comments, this won't work with STL containers since they have **2** template parameters: one for the elements type, the other one for the type of the allocator used for managing storage allocation (which has a default value).

Consequently, you need to change the first template parameter so that it has two parameters:

```
template <template <typename,typename> class CollectionType, class ItemType>
class Test
{
public:
    CollectionType<ItemType> m_collection;
};
```

But wait, that won't work either! Indeed, `CollectionType` awaits another parameter, the allocator... So now you have two solutions:

1 . Enforce the use of a particular allocator:

```
CollectionType<ItemType, std::allocator<ItemType> > m_collection
```

2 . Add a template parameter for the allocator to your class:

```
template <template <typename,typename> class CollectionType, 
          class ItemType,
          class Allocator = std::allocator<ItemType> >
class Test
{
public:
    CollectionType<ItemType, Allocator> m_collection;
};
```

So as you see, you end up with something rather complicated, which seems really twisted to deal with STL containers...

My advice: see Greg Rogers' answer for a better approach :)!

Comment: That works, I don't quite understand it. What is the <class T> part doing?

Comment: This wouldn't compile for me (VS 2008), I'd to add a second type for the allocator on vector, making the template declaration be "template <template <typename, typename> class CollectionType, class ItemType>". The declaration for m_collection then became "CollectionType<ItemType, std::allocator<ItemType>>" +1 for pointing out "template template parameters", thanks :)

Comment: For an excellent tutorial on template template parameters see "http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=376878"

Comment: @BinaryWorrier, yeah I get the same error when I instantiate a Test.

Comment: @Binary Worrier You're completely right, that's what you get when you write an answer "quick and dirty" :-)! I'll change that right away.

Comment: This won't work if the implementation decides to add other parameters to std::vector. That's perfectly allowed, as long as all those have default argument. But it will break your code.

Comment: @litb, you're correct, that's one more argument in support of Greg Rogers' answer!

Comment: Hello again - I'm sorry i was wrong with that, back then! Many people say that this is allowed, but today i started to look for a *proof* in the Standard, and found that the Standard does *not* allow implementations to add additional, defaulted, parameters. See also this discussion within the committee: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#94 . Upvoted! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @litb, it is nice to see that you keep improving even old answers.

Answer (score 2):

Comeau online likes this:

```
#include <vector>

template <template <class T, class A = std::allocator<T> > class CollectionType, class ItemType>
class Test
{
public:
    CollectionType<ItemType> m_collection;
};

void foo()
{
using std::vector;
Test<vector,int>  t = Test<vector, int>();
t.m_collection = vector<int>();
}
```